# issue of re-call plugin fs.zoomer plugin for dynamic images

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

- my Jquery Code for getting Images and adding ui-li-img tages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url: "localpath/folder/",
        success: function(data){
        $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
        var images = $(this).attr("href");
        Array.push(images);
        });
        $('<ul id="imgul" />').appendTo('#imagesDiv');
   //here create dynamic ui-li-ima tage append to div
        for(var i=0;i<Array.length;i++)
        {
            $('<li>').append($('<img  class=""img-responsive/>').attr('src',"herepath" )).appendTo('#imgul');
        }
        });
       $(".demo .zoomer_basic").zoomer();// call plugin
     });
 function buttonClicked(){
  $("#imagesDiv").empty();
$(".demo .zoomer_basic .zoomer_tiled").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: "localpath/folder-1/",
        success: function(data){
        $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
        var images = $(this).attr("href");
        Array.push(images);
        });
        $('<ul id="imgul" />').appendTo('#imagesDiv');
        for(var i=0;i<Array.length;i++)
        {
            $('<li>').append($('<img  class=""img-responsive/>').attr('src',"herepath" )).appendTo('#imgul');
        }
        }); 
     $(".demo .zoomer_basic").zoomer();//recall plugin
 }
```

- My Html Code :

```
<script src="/jquery.fs.zoomer.js"></script>  
<div class="zoomer_basic" id="imagesDiv"></div>
```

And button code:

- Here initial page loding images getting forward,next,zoom controls worked corectly.
- Here i got issue is when i click on button and called  buttonClicked() function for loading other images then zoom controls and plugin controls not worked only images showing..and  i tried look into fs.zoomer.js but may be old images effecting and how to remove these from plugin.

  - used plugins are [plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/Smooth-Image-Enlargement-Plugin-Zoomer.html) and [fs.zoomer.js](https://github.com/FormstoneClassic/Zoomer/blob/master/jquery.fs.zoomer.js)